# Rosjava message description

Tags: ros, rosjava, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to get the msg definition from a running ros system. My current solution consists of recursively examining the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and reading all the .msg files. Not pretty.

Is there any special reason one cannot get at the (private) TopicDescription in the TopicDeclarations accessible through the MasterStateClient? Or is this just not a feature yet?

Is there a better way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38680/rosjava-message-description/) by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's simply not a feature yet. Please file a feature request:

http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0